# Bootsrap col-* does not work when col-*-* present, but it should be the default

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

EDIT: It works with the new Version of Bootstrap, at least for me

I am working on a webpage with Boostrap 4. As far as I know col-xs-* got deprecated with 4.0 and the default for 0px up is now col-*. 
I have set "col-6 col-md-12" but its always 12 columns wide.

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<div class="container-fluid" style="height: 100%">
  <div class="row trenner">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-12 logout">
      <button class="logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out-alt"></i><label class="btnLbl">Abmelden</label></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-right wagenMobil">
      <ul id="drop-dummy">
        <button id="wagen-button"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Screenshot small Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc1kG.png)

If I set only "col-6" it works.

If I do "col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12" it will be 12 Columns wide until the breakpoint for sm, then its 6 and goes back to 12 when the breakpoint for md is reached.

"col-xs-*" does not work with bootsrap 4 anymore.

How do I get my Column to be 6 wide for xs devices?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: col-6 col-md-12 should work, I do this every single day

Comment: please provide code because you must be doing something wrong there

Comment: did you include boostrap 4, you probably kept the 3?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] and not just a description of your code.

Comment: Added some code, but it should be exactly as described. If I had Bootstrap 3 the col-xs should have worked. As I get it overwritten with the col-sm-6 there probably isn anythin terribly wrong. It is just that the default col- gets overwritten

Comment: I converted your code to a live demo, it appears in two columns on a narrow display. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why are you using 4.0.0 instead of 4.2.1?

Comment: 4.0.0 was just what the Editor (Dreamweaver -.-) Auto-included and I did not double-check. Newest Versions seems to work, so probably just a Bug in the 4.0.0. If you post it as an answer Ill accept it @Quentin

Comment: @Mika — The code works when I test it with 4.0.0. I couldn't, in good conscience, claim that upgrading fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Chromes responsive view that caused the problem. As seen in the screenshot all elements have a calculated width of 980px no matter how small you resize it.

If I don't use the responsive view in the dev options and resize the actual Browser window it works.

PS: almost lost my mind over this what I guess is a bug.